# Improving performance on SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently having performance problems with an expensive SQL query, and I'd like to improve it.

This is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT TOP 50 MovieID 
FROM (SELECT [MovieID], COUNT(*) AS c 
      FROM [tblMovieTags]
      WHERE [TagID] IN (SELECT TOP 7 [TagID] 
                        FROM [tblMovieTags]
                        WHERE [MovieID]=12345
                        ORDER BY Relevance ASC)
      GROUP BY [MovieID]
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a
INNER JOIN [tblMovies] m ON m.MovieID=a.MovieID 
WHERE (Hidden=0) AND m.Active=1 AND m.Processed=1 
ORDER BY c DESC, m.IMDB DESC
```

What I'm trying to find movies that have at least 2 matching tags for MovieID 12345.

Database basic scheme looks like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/r5KpgkJ.png]

Each movie has 4 to 5 tags. I want a list of movies similar to any movie based on the tags. A minimum of 2 tags must match.

This query is causing my server problems as I have hundreds of concurrent users at any given time.

I have already created indexes based on execution plan suggestions, and that has made it quicker, but it's still not enough.

Is there anything I could do to make this faster?

Comment: You should cache semi-immutable stuff like this.

Comment: Suggestion 1 - never use count (*) always use count ( some_key)

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: if you are grouping by movie_id you can simply use count(movie_id) instead of count(*)

Comment: How many movies? How many tags?

Comment: What is `TOP 7` doing in the middle of this without an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel Why; worst suggestion ever.

Comment: using `count(*)` over a specified key is a very slight performance hit, however that's not what's costing the most, it's all the embedded statements.

Comment: What does the execution plan say is the costliest part of this?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel That statement is just incorrect. If `some_key` in  `count(some_key)` is anything but the clustered index of the table it will be slower than `Count(*)`. Also note that `count(some_key)` counts only non null values.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Movie database consists of about 2,000,000 and tags could be around 1,000,000.

Comment: @HABO You are right, when simplifying this example for my question, I accidentally removed it! It's in there now with a field "Relevance". This is basically an int field with the most relevant tag starts as value of 1.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom It says that 91% of the cost is happening on a Key Lookup. Here is a picture: http://i.imgur.com/CLx7dYt.png. Please note that the tblSiteTags is the tblMovieTags in my example

Comment: If you are really having performance issues why not separate the data into a single table with the results of this query for each movie in it. then update the table periodically i would imagine the tags do not change all that often. all client matches then run from this single table, where you can control the indexes and Data contained

Comment: @Yakyb I was hoping I could avoid doing it that way but its looking more like this would be the best solution.

Comment: What are the indexes? Is MovieTags indexed on TagId with MovieId as an included column? Are the index statistics current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Like to use temp tables, because they can speed up your queries (if used correctly) and make it easier to read. Try using the query below and see if it speeds it up any. There were a few fields (hidden,imdb) that weren't in your schema, so I left them out.

This query may, or may not, be exactly what you are looking for. The point of it is to show you how to use temp tables to increase the performance and improve readability. Some minor tweaks may be necessary.

```
SELECT TOP 7 [TagID],[MovieTagID],[MovieID]
INTO #MovieTags
FROM [tblMovieTags]
WHERE [MovieID]=12345

SELECT mt.MovieID, COUNT(mt.MovieTagID)
INTO #Movies
FROM #MovieTags mt
INNER JOIN tblMovies m ON m.MovieID=mt.MovieID AND m.Active=1 AND m.Process=1
GROUP BY [MovieID]
HAVING COUNT(mt.MovieTagID) > 1

SELECT TOP 50 * FROM #Movies 
DROP TABLE #MovieTags
DROP TABLE #Movies
```

**Edit**

*Parameterized Queries*

You will also want to use parameterized queries, rather than concatenating your values in your SQL string. Check out this [short, to the point, blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) that explains why you should use parameterized queries. This, combined with the temp table method, should improve your performance significantly.

Comment: INNER JOIN #MovieTags tmt ON mt.MovieTagID=tmt.MovieTagID should be TagID not MovieTagID

Comment: Actually, that join isn't needed at all. I just needed to select from #MovieTags. I Edited my query.

Comment: I'm noticing that our two solutions are almost identical. Mine just uses temp tables in the background heh.

Comment: Yeah, back to your comment about the inner join; it should be joining on MovieTagID, because MovieTagID is the pk on tblMovieTags. Since you (and I was) joining back to the same table (cte_tags is a temp table of tblMovieTags), you will want to join on the pk of that table. Your query also contains the unnecessary inner join, since you should have the data that you need in the cte_tags table. Pretty darn close though.

Comment: You're putting the TagID into the #MovieTags not the MovieID. You need to get the related movies before you can get to the movie information

Comment: There, I added the rest of the fields to that first query. My join in my second query is getting the related movies. The tags table is never being used in that query, so tag id (foreign key of tags), is not needed. Look at it a little closer. Joining on tagid will give you undesired results.

Comment: #MovieTags will only have 1 MovieID even though there may be multiple instances of it, it will only have the MovieID 12345, so #Movies will only be the count of tags for MovieID 12345 as that is how it is joined to the tblMovies. I verified this with test data just to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this one, the values returned was just the count of tags in the #SiteTags and the SiteID, no other movies were returned? Cheers

Comment: Did it not return the MovieID and the Count? If you don't need the count, you can change the last query to `SELECT TOP 50 MovieID FROM #Movies`. Otherwise you can remove the count from the second query. I guess the import questions is; was this any faster than your original query?

Comment: After many hours of testing, I managed to use the temporary table style lookup to reduce average query time from 1-2seconds to 0.3 secs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I want to see if there is some unnecessary processing happening from that query you wrote. Try the following query and let us know if it's faster slower etc And if it's even getting the same data.

I just threw this together so no guarantees on perfect syntax

```
SELECT TOP 7 [TagID]
INTO #MovieTags
FROM [tblMovieTags]
WHERE [MovieID]=12345
ORDER BY TagID

;cte_movies AS
(
    SELECT
         mt.MovieID
        ,mt.TagID
    FROM
        tblMovieTags mt
                INNER JOIN #MovieTags t ON mt.TagId = t.TagId
                INNER JOIN tblMovies m ON mt.MovieID = m.MovieID
    WHERE
        (Hidden=0) AND m.Active=1 AND m.Processed=1
),
cte_movietags AS
(
    SELECT
         MovieId
        ,COUNT(MovieId) AS TagCount
    FROM
        cte_movies
    GROUP BY MovieId
)
SELECT
    MovieId
FROM
    cte_movietags
WHERE
    TagCount > 1
ORDER BY
    MovieId
GO

DROP TABLE #MovieTags
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt! I tried this but outcome was slightly worse. Average execution time on original query was around 1200 yet this query takes on average 1900 :(

Comment: How about now that it is limited to the top 7 tags ordered by the tagID?

Comment: The first time I ran this query, it took 6500ms, every time after that it takes 1500ms. Still too slow for what I need due to high number of requests for this query :(